# ng-repeat repeats the div the directive is on

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in selectedCategory">
    <div class="repertoire-composer">
        <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#compositions{{$index}}"
             class="repertoire-composer-title">
            <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>
            {{item.composer}}
            <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="compositions{{$index}}" ng-repeat="composition in item.compositions" class="repertoire-compositions collapse">
            <div class="repertoire-composition">
                {{composition}}
                <span class="fa fa-remove" title="Remove"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So what I basically want is to have a tree of multiple `.repertoire-composer` divs, each of which with one or many child `.repertoire-composition` inside its `.repertoire-compositions` div. So in the second repeat, angular should create one or more `.repertoire-composition` divs. However, what it seems to do is create more divs of the one the directive is on. Hope I've been explicit enough, here's the unwanted result:

[image]

So basically, why is my `.repertoire-compositions` div getting duplicated?

**EDIT:**

I was misunderstanding `ng-repeat`. This is the intended behaviour of it: to repeat the element the directive is on. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: .repertoire-compositions is not being duplicated it's being actually ng-repeated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.repertoire-compositions` is not being duplicated it's being actually ng-repeated by this part of your template:

```
<div id="compositions{{$index}}" ng-repeat="composition in item.compositions" class="repertoire-compositions collapse">
```

Comment: Isn't this line supposed to duplicate this div's content as many times as items in the collection? You can see in the example there's multiple `.repertoire-compositionS`

Comment: no, this line is REPEATING this tag and what's inside of it for each item in the collection; in resulting DOM you have as many .repertoire-compositionS as items you have in the each item.compositions array

Comment: Seems like I was misunderstanding this directive. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Good that it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because of the second ng-repeat on item.compositions, can you provide a set of data ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try this in the inner repeater:

```
<div id="compositions{{$index}}"  class="repertoire-compositions collapse">
        <div class="repertoire-composition" ng-repeat="composition in item.compositions">
            {{composition}}
            <span class="fa fa-remove" title="Remove"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```